# WiFi stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04 on HP envy x360

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, internet, hp

I had a few problems with my laptop earlier related to sudo not working, and then disk space issues. After solving that, the only problem remaining is WiFi not working, which was Ok before all that. I'm afraid I've done something to corrupt it inadvertently. Please help, I really need my computer working, and I had a ton of trouble with it recently. Thanks a lot in advance.

I know this information might not be enough to get concrete help, so please tell me what command you want me to run. I tried pressing F12, but it didn't help. When I open the WiFi window to connect to a network, the message I see is
"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found
Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on"

I repeat, I did have WiFi until hours ago. It's frustrating because I don't have the right ethernet cable for my laptop, so it's offline and I can't do any real work because of that.

I try

```
lshw -C network
network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
```

In addition

```
iwconfig
lo  no wireless extensions.
```

If I try

```
rfkill list

0: hci: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked:np
```

Then

```
lspcu -knn | grep Net -A3

03:00:00 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] )rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless 7265 [8086:5010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Additionally

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[3.665367] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[3.735228] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265 REV=0z210
[3.757097] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 5c:5f:67:9a:f3:d0
[3.824990] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[3.826388] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You had WiFi and it stopped working all of a sudden, do you either hit the keyboard key that's locks WiFi or you have a conflicting program with your ip, if that's the case is dhcp running and have you looked at dmesg and journalctl at all

Comment: You might try manually forcing the wifi adapter on after removing it and re enabling it with the verbose method

Comment: How would I do that, can you please give me detailed instructions?

Comment: Also dmesg gives too long output, please tell me specifically what to grep for, so I can paste it in the original question above.

Comment: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Please see the added information I have included above

Comment: It looks OK. Run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`